# why "use function" is returning "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function" if function exists?

Tags: php, composer-php

My composer json contains this piece of code:

```php
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

In file src/Sensorario/run.php I've the function run.

```php
namespace App\Sensorario;

function run() {
    // do something
}
```

In file public/index.php I've this code:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use function App\Sensorario\run;

$result = run();
```

But I do not understand I receive this error message:

```bash
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function App\Sensorario\run()
```

I've been used

- composer dump-autload
- cmposer install
- checked all composer's generated file

Function exists, the path should be correct, ... I expected that a function will be exported like a class. But or this is not possibile or I need help to learn exactly how.

Comment: "I expected that a function will be exported like a class" - No, there is no such thing as function autoloading in PHP. PHP only has class autoloading.

Comment: And what about my own answer ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. That's a (very handy) feature provided by Composer itself, but it doesn't really provide function autoloading either, it just automates `include` statements, which are file based as usual.

Comment: What makes you think that this **should** work?

Comment: Please, read my answer.

Comment: If you are wondering why your answer works, it's because PHP needs you to `require` or `include` any additional file, including those that contain class definitions and function definitions. And, while the language provides a mechanism to trigger file loading on demand when using classes, it doesn't provide anything similar for functions, so you must load explicitly whatever file contains the function definition. You can do it yourself, or ask Composer to do it for you.

Comment: But, ... why you do not read my answer. Is useless add include if you are already using composer's autoloader.

Comment: The code is working ad is visible here: https://github.com/sensorario/dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the missing composer configuration.

```json
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "src/Sensorario/functions.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```